# C program skipping printf and scanf statements

Tags: c, encryption, printf, scanf, fflush

My program below conducts a Caesar's cipher in C. For some reason, after a message has been input by the user, the `printf(" \nEnter key:")` and 
`scanf("%d", &key)` statements get "jumped" over. My thought was something related to the input buffer having a char and newline entered causing the jump (hence the `fflush` attempt). How do I prevent this behavior?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char message[50], ms;
    int i, key, choice;

    printf("Enter 1. to Encrypt, or 2. to Decrypt: ");
    scanf(" %d", &choice);

    printf("Enter a message to process: ");
    scanf(" %c", message);
    printf(" \nEnter key:");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%d", &key);

    for (i = 0; message[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
        ms = message[i];
        if (ms >= 'a' && ms <= 'z' && choice == 1) {
            ms = ms + key;
            if (ms >= 'a' && ms <= 'z' && choice == 2) {
                ms = ms - key;
                if (ms > 'z') {
                    ms = ms - 'z' + 'a' - 1;
                }
            }
            message[i] = ms;
        } else
        if (ms >= 'A' && ms <= 'Z' && choice == 1) {
            ms = ms + key;
            if (ms >= 'A' && ms <= 'Z' && choice == 2) {
                ms = ms - key;
            }
            if (ms > 'Z') {
                ms = ms - 'Z' + 'A' - 1;
            }
            message[i] = ms;
        }
        if (choice == 1) {
            printf(" \nEncrypted message: %s", message);}
        else if (choice == 2) {
            printf(" \nDecrypted message: %s", message);}
    }
}
```

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is never correct. `fflush` is for output, not input.

Comment: When running, I get this output: `Enter 1. to Encrypt, or 2. to Decrypt: 1
Enter a message to process: hello

Enter key:1

Encrypted message: i`. It appears that it's not skipped over for me, but there may be other issues.

Comment: Following the comment 2 back `scanf(" %c", message);` is incorrect. `message` is an array, decaying to a pointer, not a `char`. Did the compiler warn you? Mine did not but until you correct that the output is absurd.

Comment: scanf is not a great function, because of its unpredictability in consuming input on failure to perform a conversion. Consider using fgets to read input line-by-line, followed by sscanf, and also checking the return values of standard library functions.

Comment: @WeatherVane if I instead use gets(message) for example, then my printf's prompting for both the message and the key print with no waiting for user input.

Comment: `gets` is dangerous and obsolete. Please use `fgets`. Don't mix the methods. Use `fgets` and then `sscanf` on its input.

Comment: You need to get a book on the "C" language and study it. You need to understand each line of code you write. You need to understand ASCII binary encoding and values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ddisec I have noted `3 mistakes` in your code .

First your `scanf(" %c", message);` .Here you have to use `%s` *(String)*.

Second the result printing statements should be outside `for-loop`.

Third putting  `if(ms >= 'a' && ms <= 'z'&& choice == 2)` inside `if (ms >= 'a' && ms <= 'z' && choice == 1)` dose not make any sense.

Try this *corrected code*:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char message[50], ms;
    int i, key, choice;

    printf("Enter 1. to Encrypt, or 2. to Decrypt: ");
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    getchar();                                              // to handle unwanted newline.
    printf("Enter a message to process: ");
    scanf("%49[^\n]", message);
    printf(" \nEnter key:");
    scanf("%d", &key);

    for (i = 0; message[i] != '\0'; ++i)
    {
        ms = message[i];
        if (ms >= 'a' && ms <= 'z' && choice == 1)
        {
            ms = ms + key;
        }
        else if (ms >= 'a' && ms <= 'z' && choice == 2)
        {
            ms = ms - key;
        }
        else if (ms > 'z')
            {
                ms = ms - 'z' + 'a' - 1;
            }
        else if (ms >= 'A' && ms <= 'Z' && choice == 1)
        {
            ms = ms + key;
        }
        else if (ms >= 'A' && ms <= 'Z' && choice == 2)
        {
            ms = ms - key;
        }
        else if (ms > 'Z')
        {
            ms = ms - 'Z' + 'A' - 1;
        }

        message[i] = ms; // Only single modification code needed.
    }
    if (choice == 1)
    {
        printf(" \nEncrypted message: %s", message);
    }
    else if (choice == 2)
    {
        printf(" \nDecrypted message: %s", message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I did notice my printf's at the end being inside the loop. Having the choice == 2 statement inside of choice == 1's was a silly mistake on my part. Still learning a lot as I go!

Comment: You should also consider `ms < 'a'` when decrypting and we're in lower-case mode, or likewise `ms < 'A' ` in upper case, and add 26 if needed. `If (ms > 'Z') ms-=26` makes more sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

There are multple problems in your code:

- The way you enter the message is incorrect: `scanf(" %c", message);` reads a single byte into the `message` first element and does not even make it a C string. Use this instead, to read the message with embedded spaces:

  ```
  scanf("%49[^\n]", message);
  ```
- There are logic bugs in the rest of the code: for example, you test for `choice == 2` inside the block that is only executed if `choice == 1`...

Here is a simplified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char message[50];
    int i, key, choice;

    printf("Enter 1. to Encrypt, or 2. to Decrypt: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &choice) != 1)
        return 1;

    printf("\nEnter a message to process: ");
    if (scanf("%49[^\n]", message) != 1)
        return 1;
    printf("\nEnter key:");
    if (scanf("%d", &key) != 1)
        return 1;

    for (i = 0; message[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
        int ms = message[i];
        if (ms >= 'a' && ms <= 'z') {
            if (choice == 1)
                ms = 'a' + ((ms - 'a') + key) % 26;
            if (choice == 2)
                ms = 'a' + ((ms - 'a') + 26 - key) % 26;
            message[i] = ms;
        } else
        if (ms >= 'A' && ms <= 'Z') {
            if (choice == 1)
                ms = 'A' + ((ms - 'A') + key) % 26;
            if (choice == 2)
                ms = 'A' + ((ms - 'A') + 26 - key) % 26;
            message[i] = ms;
        }
    }
    if (choice == 1)
        printf("\nEncrypted message: %s\n", message);
    if (choice == 2)
        printf("\nDecrypted message: %s\n", message);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice, this does seem far simpler. However, this code doesn't seem to work when I build/run in VS17.

Comment: @ddisec: try this modified version with `ms` defined as `int`. What is the error message?